# c# mysql webhosting connection fail server

Tags: c#, mysql, cpanel, visual-studio-2017

Hi I'm having a problem with my windows form application. It was working fine until I migrated my DB from localhost to a web host. I activate "MYSQL REMOTE" but I can't connect my application to the database. Instead, I get this error message:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts

I tried to disable the Windows firewall and didn't work. I also tried to connect from mysql workbench but don't work either. I´m using the same PC that manage the Cpanel, don't know if that's my problem.

My connection string is this

```
server = "miServidor";
dataBase = "miBaseDatos";
user = "miUsuario";
password = "miContraseña"; 
string cadenaConeccion;
cadenaConeccion = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + dataBase + ";" + "UID=" + user + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
coneccion = new MySqlConnection(cadenaConeccion)
```

Comment: Have you checked if you can access the database from a different machine? If not then you should take it up with your host.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to config the firewall on the Webserver. Normal only the ports 80 and 443 are open for http and https, maybe some other.
So you have to config the Firewall and look at the mysql help, wich ports you have to open to outside and inside.

Comment: Thank you, how can I open a port on a web server?

Comment: What kind of Server do you have? Is it Windows or Unix? If it is a Windows Server, then go to the Systemsettings and there you can find the config interface for the firewall. If it is an Unix Server, then you have to use google.